# How can I replace a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I think it's very easy but I have no idea how to do that.
I tried by attribuition, doing a list receive another list but don't work.

```
% H is the head of a coordenate and T the tail
% E is the element that will be placed in the position T
findLine([L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10],H,T,E,NewTray) :-
    H is 1,replace(L1,T,E,N),L1 = N;
    H is 2,replace(L2,T,E,N),L2 = N;
    ...
    H is 10,replace(L10,T,E,N),L10 = N;
    NewTray = [L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10].
```

I need that L1 be the N in this clause, I don't know how I can create a clause to modify the L1 inside the clause findLine. I thought in create clause to remove all elements and add the new ones one by one and call this at the attribuition place:

```
%L is the list, C a counter and N the new list
 rewrite(L,C,N) :- 
        Q is C,
        removeByIndex(Q,L,R),
        (Q \== 0 ->  rewrite(R,Q-1,N), !.

    removeByIndex(0,[_|T],T):- !.
    removeByIndex(I,[H|T],R):- X is I - 1, removeByIndex(X, T, Y), insert(H, Y, R).
```

But I continous with the same problem: the L1 are not modified :(

The idea is modify a line and replace on the tray.

PS: I'm sorry for my english, but the prolog topics are almost inative in the portuguese forum

Comment: What is `T`? What is `E`? You need to give more details of what you want these predicates to do. Some examples would be good.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really unsure what you're trying to accomplish here, but I can point to a few things that strike me as symptoms of a misunderstanding.

First of all, you bind all the variables at the top and then you have essentially a bottom-out else case that looks like this:

```
NewTray = [L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10].
```

Well, you never assign to `NewTray` in any of your other cases, so `NewTray` is going to be uninstantiated most of the time. That does not seem likely to be what you intend to me.

Second, your cases have this structure:

```
H is 1,replace(L1,T,E,N),L1 = N;
```

First mistake here is that `H is 1`; `is/2` is for evaluating arithmetic expressions; there's no difference between this and `H = 1`, and the equivalence of `L1` and `N` means that this whole predicate could probably be written as:

```
findLine([L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10],1,T,E,_) :-
    replace(L1,T,E,L1).
findLine([L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10],2,T,E,_) :-
    replace(L2,T,E,L2).
findLine(Line, _, _, Line).
```

I'm still confused by what you're trying to do, looking at that.

I suspect that you think `L1` will have some value on the way into the relation and suddenly have a new, different value after the relation is used. That is emphatically **not** the case: variables in Prolog are bound exactly once; your assignment `L1 = N` or whatever is not going to *cause* L1 to "receive a new value" (because such a thing cannot happen in Prolog); instead it informs Prolog that L1 and N should be bound to the same value. What this means depends on circumstances; if they are both ground and not equal it will cause your predicate to fail, for instance, but if either of them is non-ground they will accept the value of the other.

I'm looking at what you're doing here and I can't help but think that you're essentially trying to do this:

```
replace([], _, _, []).
replace([H|T], 1, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], N, X, [H|Replaced]) :- 
  N > 1, succ(N0, N), replace(T, N0, X, Replaced).
```

Use it like this:

```
?- replace([1,2,3,4,5], 3, foo, Result).
Result = [1, 2, foo, 4, 5]
```

I just can't for the life of me figure out what you're trying to do, and I don't know why you're bothering to bind all the variables in your list at once if you don't need them all at once.

Anyway, I hope this helps! Maybe if you show us more of what you're trying to do it will be more clear how we can help.

**Edit**: Elaboration on `=` and unification

Let's mess around with `=` and see what happens:

```
?- X = 3.
X = 3.
```

Probably nothing surprising about this.

```
?- 3 = X.
X = 3.
```

Unification is different from assignment. As you can see, it is not directional. This line would not have worked in any other language.

```
?- X = [1,Y,3].
X = [1, Y, 3].
```

Notice that Prolog has no issues with having variables remain free.

```
?- X = [1,Y,3], Y = 2.
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = 2.
```

Now, because Y is the same in both positions, when you bound Y to 2, the middle value in X became 2 as well. There are data structures unique to Prolog that make use of this feature (difference lists).

```
?- X = [1,Y,3], Q = X, Q = [1,2,3].
X = Q, Q = [1, 2, 3],
Y = 2.
```

Now what makes this interesting is that we did not explicitly tell Prolog that Y is 2. Prolog inferred this by unification. You can see some more examples of that here:

```
?- X = [H|T], H = 3, T = [4,5].
X = [3, 4, 5],
H = 3,
T = [4, 5].
```

So here we said, X is composed of H and T and then told it what H and T are. But Prolog's unification doesn't care much about the order you do things:

```
?- X = [H|T], X = [1,2,3].
X = [1, 2, 3],
H = 1,
T = [2, 3].
```

Unification is transitive.

So what happens when Prolog cannot unify?

```
?- X = [1,Y,3], Q = X, Q = [1,2,3], Y = 4.
false.
```

Y has to be 2 for the first step, but it has to be 4 for the last step. Once a variable is bound, there's no changing it. This is just a more complex way of saying:

```
?- X = 2, X = 4.
false.
```

Prolog does not have "assignables", just variables.

Comment: Can you give a example of what did you said: "but if either of them is non-ground they will accept the value of the other"? My problem is basically this, I need that L1 to be modified because I'm refreshing my tray (or board, I don't know). It's a naval battle game

Comment: @Marcio there's no modifying variables in Prolog

Comment: @Marcio I have elaborated a bit, see the updated answer.

Comment: To use some other example than lists: the equality ```f(X,b) = f(a,Y)``` holds exactly if ```X=a``` and ```Y=b```; the variable assignment to make the left hand side equal to the right hand side is called unifier and the process itself is called [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)).